# How to add 100GB from Windows 7 to Ubuntu?

Tags: 10.04

Windows 7 has way too much free space, is it possible to get 100GB from Windows7 and give it to Ubuntu? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Yes:

1. Get either a Ubuntu Live CD or a bootable USB stick.
2. Boot your system using this Live CD or USB.
3. Select "Try Ubuntu without installing"
4. Once Ubuntu boots, look for the partition editor (tap the Windows key, then type gparted to find it).

Using gparted you can first shrink your Windows partition and then expand the Ubuntu one to claim the unused space.

Be warned:

- This operation will take a while.
- **BACK UP YOUR DATA**.  There are NO guarantees that things won't go wrong. NO utility can guarantee that, so ALWAYS BACK UP YOUR DATA before trying something like this.

Apologies for using caps, but it's important. **Back up your data**.

Answer (score 0):

Download EASEUS Partition Manager, it is free, just be careful that you do not destroy your windows partition, resize the partition to a second one for 100GB, then apply and it will allocate that much from your already existing partition without destroying windows.  Then you can install Ubuntu on the new partition you created.

http://www.filehippo.com/download_easeus_partition_master_home/

Comment: in using EASEUS you may lose the grub file (http://askubuntu.com/q/186068/47206). but you might have to use it nevertheless. if grub lost, the solution is this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair